# Delaunay: Triangulate two point sets with the best fitting mesh

Tags: algorithm, math, computational-geometry, triangulation

I got a cloud with randomly distributed points and another cloud with the same points but moved randomly. So each point of cloud A has a corresponding point in cloud B.

Now I want to triangulate both clouds with the same triangle mesh, finding the mesh with the least intersections in both clouds.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This has the sound of being NP hard; it requires selection of edges with certain properties.  Have you considered any heuristic methods?

Answer (score 1):

Create a random triangulation of the points in cloud A and measure the number of intersections in both A and B.  Then apply [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) to randomly add / remove / move edges which preserve the triangulation features you're interested in preserving and measuring the number of intersections after each iteration.

As a starting point, if you don't want to start with a random set of edges, you could start out with the Delauny triangulation in A, and then measure the total number of intersections in B.  Proceed with the simulated annealing method as before.

Comment: So this is kind of a brute force approach?

Comment: Simulated Annealing is not brute force; it's not guaranteed to find an optimal solution.  It may find one that is good enough, and do it in a reasonable period of time.  As I said in the comment to your question, this sounds like it might be an NP hard problem making brute force methods impractical.  Since I haven't worked out whether it is or is not NP hard, it's entirely possible (maybe even likely) my initial reaction is wrong, and it's easier than NP hard.  If that's the case, there exists a polynomial time algorithm to find an optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

First very simple approach, make (Delaunay) triangulation on the half moved positions and use it for both clouds. That can produce good result if movement is not too large.

Triangulation have intersections iff there are negative oriented triangles. So, good triangulation for both clouds consists of triangles that are positive oriented in both clouds.

Approach can be, quite similar what andand mentioned, to create initial triangulation on cloud A and try to locally repair negative oriented triangles in cloud B. Probably standard flipping can solve it.

I think it is possible to check which points (area) can't be triangulated good in both clouds, with making intersection of positive oriented triangles on both clouds and looking for points that are not in any triangle of the intersection. For this it is enough (needed) to take triangles of node for a neighboring area (with a neighboring nodes).